# References for generalized confluent hypergeometric differential equation

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, hypergeometric-functions

According to [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralConfluentHypergeometricDifferentialEquation.html), a generalization of the confluent hypergeometric differential equation is given by:
$$y''+\left(\frac{2R}{x}+2F'+p\frac{H'}{H}-H'-\frac{H''}{H'}\right) y'+\left[\left(p\frac{H'}{H}-H'-\frac{H''}{H'}\right)\left(\frac{R}{x}+F'\right)+\frac{R(R-1)}{x^2}+\frac{2R}{x}F'+F''+(F')^2-\frac{q}{H}(H')^2 \right]y=0,$$
which has the solutions $y_1=x^{-R} e^{-F} M(q,p,H)$ and $y_2=x^{-R} e^{-F} O(q,p,H)$, where $M(q,p,H)$  is the confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind and $O(q,p,H)$ is the confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind. Meanwhile, $R$, $F$ and $H$ are functions of $x$.

I tried to look on google for more details about this equation but I didn't find anything. Can anyone here please give me more references about this particular equation? Like how it was derived, the relation between the parameters $p$ and $q$, etc.

Comment: "This question is urgent" and "please upvote" are not appropriate.  I have edited them out.